# Is there a name for a term that is statistically possible but impossible like the following for Powerball?

Tags: statistics

Example all numbers supposedly have the same statistical chance for being the winning Powerball number (the Powerball Number plus 5 other number) yet there has never been nor will there ever be consecutive winning powerball numbers that are the same winning numbers (i.e. 1 4 9 12 17 48  followed by the next drawing with the numbers 1  4  9  12  17  48 of which 1 is the Powerball #). ANother example is a winning number  of 1 2 3 4  5  6. Statistics says this is possible ye t I maintain it is not because if you randomly draw 6 numbers for a whole year the same way, 1000 an hour, that number combo will still not be drawn even though statistically it has the same chance of being drawn as an other number combo.

Comment: Your example is not impossible, it is improbable.  Any lottery ticket comes with an equally improbable sequence of numbers on it and people win the jackpot ever so frequently, so a valid arbitrary sequence winning is certainly not impossible, just highly improbable.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible, you say?  Well then, I propose a bet.  I'll give you a dollar.  If the next Powerball draw comes up 1 2 3 4 5 6, you give me 1 billion dollars.

What?  According to you, it's a free dollar for you - there's no way I can possibly win.

So how about I give you two dollars, and if either 1 2 3 4 5 6 or 1 2 3 4 5 7 come up, you give me a billion dollars.

According to you, both outcomes are impossible.  So this is a free $2 for you.

So how about I give you \$175,223,510, and if any of... what's that you say?  You've changed your mind?

Comment: Nah if I had the money I wouldn't change my mind. I wish there was some lab that would randomly generate 6 number combos non-stop for a year and at the end of the year, I maintain that even though statistically the number 1,2,3,4,5,6 could be drawn and the same 2 numbers could be drawn one after another, they won't. Nor will other number combos even though statistically they should. I think there should be some kind of scientific name for this (there were several names answered) Same way the odds of the Magic Bullet Theory Happening in a Presidential Assassination (JFK) prove multiple shooters

Comment: @Phil  You have completely failed to grasp the point of Nate's answer.  The number of possible outcomes in the game is 175223510; therefore, if he were to pay you one dollar for each ticket, but the payoff is 1 billion dollars, he is **guaranteed** to win even though the chance that any single outcome is the winning one is very small.  His net winnings would be approximately 825 million dollars.

Comment: Suppose that I hold a raffle.  I give out 1000 raffle tickets numbered 1 to 1000.  I then choose at random a number from 1 to 1000, and the person holding that number wins the raffle.  Each person has a 0.001 probability of winning, but **someone is guaranteed to win**.  Now if I do the same but with 100 million tickets, and you were given one of these tickets, then your chance of winning is tiny, only 0.00000001, but again, **somebody** has to win.  It just isn't likely to be you.  However, that doesn't mean it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is "insignificant probability".  You can compute the chance. The number of Powerball draws seems to be $35{59 \choose 5} =175,223,510$, so the chance that the next draw (assuming they are truly random-not necessarily a good assumption at this level of probability) matches the last one is $1/175,223,510$.  You are correct that we are unlikely to see this in our lifetimes.  It *could* happen.  This is not a mathematical concept-the chance that any given ticket wins the lottery is very small, but it is *not* zero, as shown by the fact that some people do win.

Comment: This is where my mind boggles. If something could happen but never has how do we not know it is impossible to happen even though statistically it is possible?

Comment: To use the same comment I made to another reply, here's a bizarre analogy. Is it statistically possible that an Alien from another planet lands on Earth, signs a contract to play Major League Baseball and breaks the home run record? Statistically this is possible though this scenario is impossible and will never happen as stated literally in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referencing does have a name: possible. There is always a chance that this will occur, as unlikely as it may seem relative to usual probabilities in our lives. A chance of 1 in a quadrillion is still possible... Now, an extension of your problem is the phrase "almost surely". For example, let's say you choose a random real number from 0 to 1. You will "almost surely" not choose 0.5 (the chance is infinitesimal if you will), but again - still possible.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers. I am still confused though. If the same winning Powerball numbers do not happen two weeks in a row in our lifetimes (lets say we all have long lifetimes) and if the Powerball # 1 2,3,4,5,6 doesn't happen in our lifetimes how exactly can one say that this will someday occur in limitless games? I mean if all Powerball numbers have equal chances of winning wouldn't you say any number you pick still has a better chance of winning then the number 1,2,3,4,5,6 or buying the same number combination that won the previous game?

Comment: Your logic here is kind of going all over the place... let's try to figure out exactly what you are trying to say. So, are we playing with infinite games or a finite amount of games? Also, I am unfamiliar with Powerball... Can the given number set [1,2,3,4,5,6] ever be used again, or can a certain combination only be used once? I cannot answer your question with at least this (and possibly more) info

Comment: In Powerball  I believe 1 Powerball Number is drawn randomly from numbers 1-35 and then 5 more numbers are drawn from numbers 1 to 59 (this may have changed). To win the Grand Prize you have to pick the exact Powerball number and then the remaining 5 numbers drawn though not in order). It is possible that the same (first) Powerball Number is also drawn in the 5 other numbers. I maintain though yes it is statistically possible the number 1  2,3,4,5,6 will never be drawn nor will the same 6 number combo be drawn 2 straight drawings. Basically statistically possible but impossible

Comment: Then my answer stands. When we say "impossible" in daily conversation we still mean "statistically impossible", so your sentence makes no sense. This is very much both statistically possible *and* simply "possible". The word "possible" just means it could happen, and this is true... it is very unlikely, but it could happen. The word you are looking for is *improbable*

Comment: Or to be redundant, you computer generate for an entire year non-stop, thousands of  6 number combos from a field of 35 numbers for the first number and a field of 59 numbers for the last 5 numbers), statistics say the number combo  1,2,3,4,5,6 should appear at least once and there should be at least one consecutive repetition of the same 6 number combo in a row and I say it won't happen. Even if you did this for 30 years it wouldn't happen though logically (statistically) it should

Comment: I respectfully disagree

Comment: OK Here's a bizarre analogy. Is it statistically possible that an Alien from another planet lands on Earth, signs a contract to play Major League Baseball and breaks the home run record? Statistically this is possible though this scenario is impossible and will never happen as stated literally in this sentence.

Comment: This scenario is **extremely improbable**. We have to declare that aliens are impossible before you can say the scenario is impossible, and science cannot currently do that (nor does science really *ever* give something as impossible, since science is about observations).

Comment: WSC's comment on your original post clarifies this very well... if you are expecting some mathematician to say differently you are on the wrong forum. Everyone here has given you correct answers based on probability fundamentals. If you choose to use the word *impossible* in place of *improbable* all is well, but if you try to convince someone that probability is wrong because of the different notation you won't get anywhere.

Comment: My scenario with the Alien playing major league baseball is what I call impossible based on the odds of: 1. An alien landing on Earth, 2. Deciding to Play Major League Baseball and 3. Breaking the Major League record.

Comment: I'm lost in your distinction between improbable and impossible. The odds on someone playing major league baseball are improbable but obviously possible and thus very high odds against. The idea of an Alien landing on Earth playing Major League Baseball and breaking the home run record you say is also improbable. How can they be the same?  Wouldn't you say statistically the odds of the alien playing baseball and breaking the record are astronomically (pun intended) higher than the odds of a human playing major league baseball yet you call both improbable. How can they both be improbable if so

Comment: They are both, by definition, improbable. I don't want to try to convince you that mathematical definitions are correct (it would just waste my time), I'll try once more. Imagine putting the Sun and a lightbulb right next to each other. We wouldn't even notice the light-bulb producing light, but that doesn't mean it isn't. Take this analogy to probability. There is (probably, it's debatable) a greatly lower probability that aliens will arrive and do as you said; however, you do say that it's possible (even if astronomically higher) and is thus, by definition, improbable

Comment: Improbable simply means that it could happen, but it's unlikely (how unlikely is irrelevant; in fact, sometimes entirely irrelevant with infinite trials). Impossible means something could never happen, under any circumstances. You have brought up two cases that have very different probabilities, but neither can be ruled out as being impossible, so they are simply improbable to varying degrees

Comment: OK I understand your distinction but isn't there a term for something beyond improbable that is not "Impossible"?